# Можно ли создать динамическое количество массивов в цикле python?

Tags: python, массивы

На ввод подается N - число жюри
Для каждого из жюри нужно создать отдельный массив.
Есть ли возможность реализоать это в Python? Если да, то как?

Comment: Чем вам список не динамичен?

Comment: храните ваши массивы не как отдельные переменные, а положите их внутрь другого массива или словаря

Comment: Про элементы другого массива я тоже думал, но можно ли сгенерировать новый массив, например, в цикле?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант через словарь, где ключ - номер жюри, а значение - его динамический список:

```
dict_data = {}
for i in range(int(input('Введите количество Жюри: '))):
    dict_data[i]=[]
print('Мои так нужные динамические списки для жюри по номерам:')
for NumberJury, dinSp in dict_data.items():
    print(NumberJury, ':', dinSp)
```

Пример работы:

```
Введите количество Жюри: 5
Мои так нужняе динамические списки для жюри по номерам:
0 : []
1 : []
2 : []
3 : []
4 : []
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ!